# multiple pages Analysis in Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE)

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

is it possible to create multiple pages Analysis in Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you're actually trying to do, but...

You can use a pivot table, and by putting a column in the 'pages' area you will get a drop-down on that column with a different page for each value.

The true way to have different pages of analysis would be to use a Dashboard with different pages (there's the option to add pages using the icon towards the top of the 'edit dashboard' screen), potentially using the drill/interaction functionality to move between them.

BI Publisher would of course be the other alternative to look in to.

Comment: jackohug, well, actually I thought I can create multiple sheets of Analysis like in Excel. Ok, I should learn about Dashboard. Thanks.